# Как вызвать эту функцию (void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)) в main?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется такая функция:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        other.transform.position = respawn.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как её правильно вызвать в главной функции?
Вообще весь код выглядит так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DieSpaceScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject respawn;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            other.transform.position = respawn.transform.position;
        }
    }
    void Update (){
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите? Функция OnTriggerEnter2D вызывается сама, при пересечении объектов. В Юнити скриптах нет "Главной" функции. Где и что вы хотите вызвать?

Comment: @МаксимФисман , спасибо за объяснение работы функции, но тогда можете ли вы мне объяснить, как проверять на столкновение 2-х коллайдеров, так скажем, более корректно? Извиняюсь, если задаю слишком глупые вопросы, ведь я только начинаю изучать технологию создания игр на "Unity", и ещё не до конца разобрался во всех встроенных функциях в движке.

Comment: Объясню в ответах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечаю на сам вопрос и вопрос заданный в комментариях.

Вы должны взять несколько объектов, столкновение которых хотите обрабатывать. Их них выбираете главный объект, например, игрока, и остальные, например, ну не знаю, чекпоинты (контрольные точки).
На игрока вы вещаете компоненты [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) (или другой коллайдер с другой формой, например, CircleCollider2D), И компонент Rigidbody2D, чтобы симулировать физику игроку. Если ваш игрок начинает проваливаться (это абсолютно нормально, ведь один из компонентов физики - гравитация), то в компоненте [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) выберите [isKinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html), чтобы отключить симуляцию физики (это не реальная физика, а лишь ее симуляция, во-первых, потому что объект двухмерный, а во-вторых, потому что игра - не реальный мир, и вся физика, которую мы видим в комп. играх - лишь симуляция физики, просчитанная компьютером).

Так вот, а к чекпоинтам, или объектам, с которыми игрок может столкнуться цепляете BoxCollider2d.
На игроке у вас должен висеть скрипт, в котором должна быть функция:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        
    }
```

Эта функция вызывается САМА, когда игрок сталкивается с другим объектом. Однако, обратите внимание, что компонент rigidbody на игроке делает его твердым телом, а значит игрок упрется в чекпоинт и не пройдет мимо, поэтому можно сделать чекпоинт триггером, а функция изменить на

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        
    }
```

Также обратите внимание на то, что на сцене могут быть другие объекты с collider'ами, поэтмоу функция будет вызываться при соприкосновении не только чекпоинтов, но и, например, земли. Поэтому вам следует добавить чекпоинтам тег "Чекпоинт" (на англ.), а в функции проверять, является ли объект, с которым столкнулся игрок нашим чекпоинтом:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Checkpoint") {
            // Делаем что-нибудь интересное
}
    }
```

P.S. В функциях OnCollisionEnter2D и OnTriggerEnter2D параметр collision тоже устанавливается сам, в нем хранится ссылка на компонент коллайдера объекта, с которым столкнулся игрок.

P.P.S. Помимо функции [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) (вызывается в кадр, когда игрок с чем-то сталкивается) существует [OnCollisionStay2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html) (Вызывается каждый кадр, когда игрок с чем-то пересекается) и [OnCollisionExit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit2D.html) (вызывается 1 кадр, когда игрок перестает контактировать с другим объектом). Та же ситуация и с триггерными функцими.

P.P.P.S. Пример с игроком и чекпойнтами - просто пример, в вашем случае объекты, естественно, будут другие

P.P.P.P.S. Если остались вопросы, не стесняйтесь задавать в комментарии к ответу, если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку, тем самым его приняв

Comment: Ну и в принципе, при необходимости, можно обращаться к необходимым свойствам collision.gameObject (объекта, на котором висит Collider2D компонент), если помимо тэга нужны какие-то данные из внутреннего мира цели, с которой мы столкнулись.

Comment: collision, параметр функций OnCollisionEnter, OnTriggerEnter и т.д., устанавливается сам и является полноценной переменной типа данных Collision (либо Collision2D). Мы можем, обратясь к ней через `.gameObject` спокойно получать любые компоненты данной переменной. В ней будет храниться ссылка тот объект, С которым произошел коллайд. Я не совсем понял, что вы хотели сказать вашим комментарием, если в нем подразумевался вопрос или уточнение, я смогу ответить, если вы зададите его более четко:)

Comment: Я подробно описал эту тему [здесь](/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)